# next & previous button not working properly in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, buttonclick

I m new to Jquery I have created example jquery mobile in this if back and login button is used once then next(>>) and prevoius(<<) button display the same page not that which is refferd using **href** tag. Before using Back button and login button it work fine afterusing those button it works abnormally.

edit and to view demo  http://jsfiddle.net/khushbujoshi/JERG4/5/

Answer (score 0):

DOM Element IDs are unique don't use them twice.

You don't need to do the page change on your own with jQuery. Let jQuery-mobile handle it.

Comment: i removed it still same results